# Keeps re selecting disco repo's upon reboot

Tags: 19.04

I've found I have issues with my repo's for disco anytime I restart my computer. If I go back into Software & Updates, the repo's I deselected are re-selected. Here is what I get when I try to install things:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                      
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease           
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]   
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                      
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Reading package lists... Done        
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What I have currently selected when I reboot is:

Canonical Partners (Source Code)

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable
http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco
```

(NOT the Source Code version, I've noticed no matter which one I choose it still happens.) Changing server location also doesn't do anything.

Sources list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.04 _Disco Dingo_ - Release amd64 (20190416)]/ disco main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# # deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I opened http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu in a browser, and it doesn't support any release after bionic (18.04).  Did you check the PPA supported your release before adding it?  It doesn't so should be removed and a new source for whatever you want it for searched for.

Comment: The problem is the PPA as correctly stated in the error message. It has no contents for 19.04, it goes up to 18.04 only. If you keep that selected of course the same error will keep showing. Probably there's no problem with the other ones you disabled.

Comment: @guiverc Dang it, no I assumed it was supported. How can I correct this? I was trying to install something similar to Rufus and UNetBootin was recommended

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)   It's a good idea to check PPAs are still maintained, and support your release  (for security reasons alone, they are 3rd party sources - so security is up to you).

Comment: I've used neither program, I'm writing a thumb-drive now (what I assume you want it for), but just use `dd`   Additional note:  If you're new to GNU/Linux - avoid `dd` as mistakes are costly.  I wiped a hdd a few months ago due to careless mistake.  `dd` has no margin for error.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you! I'm still really new to Linux. Could you dumb `dd` down for me?

Comment: In the main page, in this case https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa - if you click on "technical details" you'll see a dropdown menu with all the releases that PPA supports. But you don't need Unetbootin. Your Ubuntu already has similar tool for the same purpose that generally works better. Of course there's also the command-line `dd` but I'm not even talking about that.

Comment: @guiverc I was able to remove it using `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gezakovacs/ppa` Thank you!!

Comment: @guiverc I am new to Linux and I try to avoid commands because I'm worried about messing something up. That's why I've been sticking to programs, haha.

Comment: @LeslieLemon Commands are great if you know what are you doing and why.